# Gradle gets wrong version from local artifactory

Tags: android, gradle, artifactory

I put this lines in my build.gradle file:

```
compile('org.crcis:common:1.0.19@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

and this is my buildscript configs:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven{
            url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2'
        }
        maven{
            url 'http://buildautomation.crcis.local:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local'
            credentials{
                username ''
                password ''
            }
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.+'
        classpath 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.6.1'
        classpath 'org.crcis:date-utils:1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven{
            url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2'
        }
        maven{
            url 'http://buildautomation.crcis.local:8081/artifactory/libs-release-local'
            credentials{
                username ''
                password ''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to get the 1.0.19 version but it always get me 1.0.30 because 1.0.30 is the latest version in artifactory.
how can I force it to get the version I want not the latest.

Comment: Look at `gradle dependencies`

Comment: use `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'` remove `+`

Comment: @intellij-amiya Thanks for comment but not worked for me

Comment: @jared-burrows Could you please explain more :)

Comment: `gradle dependencies`

Comment: use `compile` instead of `classpath` .modify your `gradle dependencies`

Comment: remove `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.+'` from `dependencies`

Comment: @jared-burrows Are you sure? can't build the project without this line

Comment: As @JaredBurrows said don't modify the script just run from terminal `gradle dependencies` a check if there are no version conflicts - view the list   and look for the library that is causing the problem.

Comment: @Opal after using `gradle dependencies` I get `BUILD SUCCESSFUL` message

Comment: Ok, was there dependency tree printed out?

Comment: @Opal This is all what I get : `WARNING: Dependency org.json:json:20080701 is ignored for noorDebug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android. In case of problem, please repackage with jarjar to change the class packages :dependencies ------------------- Root project ------------------- No configurations BUILD SUCCESSFUL`

Comment: Strange, you don't get the dependencies tree?

Comment: site note: the dependency notation `org.crcis:common:1.0.19@aar` is artifact only and won't respect any transitive dependencies. so you can remove the `transitive = true` flag from your build script.

Comment: @ReneGroeschke I removed it and nothing changed